# Display image onclick with a button

Tags: html, button

Using html, Create a webpage with the following properties: 
Create two buttons- turnon and turnoff. 
Use on.png and off.png such that

a) If a user clicks on the turnon button, the webpage should display on.png (picture of a lightbulb on).

b) If a user clicks on the turnoff button, the webpage should display off.png (picture of a lightbulb off)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Lightbulb</title>  
</head>

<body>

    <div style="text-align: center">

        <input type="button" value="turnon"
               onclick= showimage(img src="on.png") >

        <input type="button" value="turnoff"
               onclick= showimage(img src="off.png")>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showImage() {
  document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideImage() {
  document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="TURN ON" onclick="showImage();" />
<input type="button" value="TURN OFF" onclick="hideImage();" />
<img id="loadingImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQB7V.jpg?s=48&g=1" style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Live Working Example**](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/yqomg2iXz4kUhy2x)

Actually you need to read, using javascript functions

Javascript functions => https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp
Set image source => https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp

Here is a helping link, you could find on google
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb